# How to find the current caret/cursor index of a contenteditable=true <p> tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, stenciljs, dom-selection

I am really struggling to find an answer that works for my use case. I need to have awareness of where in the contentEditable

tag the cursor/caret is.

I have tried various solutions and always get the same issue, caret solution is equal to 0.

Here is a sandbox example. If I could get it working here, I could get it working in my actual app.

Any assistance desired:

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core'

@Component({
  tag: 'my-editable-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-editable-component.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyEditableComponent {
  editableRef: HTMLParagraphElement

  getCaretPosition() {
    const selection = window.getSelection()
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
      const preCaretRange = range.cloneRange()
      preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(this.editableRef)
      preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
      return preCaretRange.toString().length
    }
    return 0
  }

  handleInput = () => {
    console.log('Caret position:', this.getCaretPosition())
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p ref={el => (this.editableRef = el as HTMLParagraphElement)} contentEditable onInput={this.handleInput}>
          Click to edit text and log caret position
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**FIRST EDIT**

After the first answer to this question I want to provide some more context around my use case and the issues I have seen tso far.

I am building a document editing application. For the scope of this discussion, users just need to be able to edit paragraphs. So far so good.

I feel that I have hit a brick wall as I have begun trying to interact with the caret.

The basic architecture of my application:

```
<document-editor >
 <document-paragraph />
</document-editor>
```

Most of the functions exist in document-editor and are passed to the children where necessary. The same goes for the state management.

Both the parent and child stencil component have `shadow: true`

One of the major issues I am facing is that I cannot access the `getSelection()` on HTMLElement.shadowRoot.getSelection() as I get a compiler issue.

I believe this is marked as part of the non-standard api according to [MDN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQpVR.png).

I am going to add some more verbose code snippets below. Please note at the time of writing they are not expected to work and are a recent synthesis of the first answer to this post. One of the blockers here is the above linked non-standard api issue.

The function I am using to return the current caret position is passed to the child document-paragraph as a prop where it is invoked onKeyUp.

Here is the function:

```
getCurrentCaretIndex = (): number => {
// return (this.blockRefs.get(`block-id-${this.blocks[this.currentBlockIndex].id}`).querySelector('#editable-content') as HTMLTextAreaElement).selectionStart
// const documentParagraph = this.blockRefs.get(`block-id-${this.blocks[this.currentBlockIndex].id}`) as HTMLElement

const thisComponent = this.el

const documentComponent = this.blockRefs.get(`block-id-${this.blocks[this.currentBlockIndex].id}`)

const element = documentComponent.shadowRoot.querySelector('#editable-content') as HTMLElement

const selection = documentComponent.shadowRoot.getSelection()

let pos = selection.rangeCount
if (pos) {
  let range = selection.getRangeAt(0)
  let cloneRange = range.cloneRange()
  cloneRange.selectNodeContents(element)
  cloneRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset)
  pos = cloneRange.toString().length
}

return pos
```

}

And my TS compiler takes issue with the use of shadowRoot.getSelection()
[image]

So at least with my current config, I cannot access the shadowRoot.selection on the documentComponent's element with ID editable-content.

It is really annoying because the caret is obviously of the utmost importance for a document editor.

I also tried using a textarea instead where I had no issues accessing the selection property but textarea does not support rich-text :/

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you copied a ChatGPT answer, without asking the correct question.

You do: `window.getSelection()` But your DOM element is inside its shadowRoot:

**Note:** Extending *Customized Built-In* Elements, like `HTMLParagraphElement` will never work in Apple/Safari. All browsers support: `extends HTMLElement`

```js
customElements.define("editable-p", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode: "open"})
           .innerHTML = `<p><b></b> <span contenteditable></span></p>`;
  }
  getCaretPosition(el = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("[contenteditable]")) {
    let selection = this.shadowRoot.getSelection(); // here ChatGPT got it wrong
    let pos = selection.rangeCount;
    if (pos) {
      let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      let cloneRange = range.cloneRange();
      cloneRange.selectNodeContents(el);
      cloneRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
      pos = cloneRange.toString().length;
    }
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector("b").innerHTML = pos;
    return pos;
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.onkeyup = (evt) => this.getCaretPosition();
    this.onfocus = (evt) => setTimeout(()=>this.getCaretPosition());
    this.onclick = (evt) => setTimeout(()=>this.getCaretPosition());
    setTimeout(()=>this.shadowRoot.querySelector("[contenteditable]").innerHTML = this.innerHTML);
  }
});
```

```html
<editable-p>Hello Web Component!</editable-p>
<editable-p>Hello Web Component World!</editable-p>
```

Comment: I appreciate this response. 

I did whip together a quick sandbox example, which gpt assisted with. Thanks for spotting that. 

I will make an edit to the original post with more context. 


As you probably noticed, I am building with stencil. I have tried to recreate youre customElement using stencil as a compiler, and I have run into quite a few of the issues I had before. See OP for details. And thank you for taking the time!

Comment: I hope my edits to the OP make sense. I tried to recreate your customElement using stencil, perhaps I missed the mark a little, but I cannot access the shadowRoot.getSelection, as it is not part of the standard api. Maybe I just need to change a config to get vscode to compile but I am very curious why this is the case specifically for a contentEditable element

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with Stencil. I stick to native only.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for trying. 

To be clear, I’m pretty sure this is not a stencil issue, as stencil is just a compiler that compiles to js. 

I’m curious to how get this line to work with my typescript, as getSelection is not part of the standard api for shadoRoot:  `  let selection = this.shadowRoot.getSelection();`

Comment: To get a reference to the component's HTML element with Stencil, you need to use the [Element Decorator](https://stenciljs.com/docs/host-element#element-decorator). So this should work: `this.el.shadowRoot.getSelection()`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The problem is that I still do not have access to shadowRoot.getSelection(). Is the solution to create a polyfill? I understand hwo to access the shadow root, its just that the getSelection method is not part of the standard api for shadowRoot.